# Openstreetmap вытянуть информацию

Tags: openstreetmap

Нужно достать координаты автобусных остановок города. Хотел скачать карту города в формате osm и парсить далее этот файл, сайт не дает это сделать - область слишком велика. Есть ли варианты найти эту информацию онлайн или все-таки скачать данную область.

Answer (score 1):

Выгрузки OSM gis-lab по регионам: http://gis-lab.info/projects/osm_dump/ 
На форуме OSM очень много информации

Answer (score 0):

Ссылку на гислабовские ежедневные выгрузки вам уже дали, а мне хотелось бы обратить ваше внимание и на способ обработки данных: можно не парсить руками полученный дамп (там XML), а загрузить его в ГИС PostGIS при помощи, например [imposm](http://imposm.org), указав, если необходимо, какие ещё данные помимо координат вам понадобятся. PostGIS — это СУБД PotgreSQL, в которую добавлены функции работы с геоданными и данные эти можно доставать из базы данных SQL-запросами.